# boilerplate has a 4mb footprint - why?

Tags: html5boilerplate

I'm using eclipse for html5, js & css3.

On starting a new project, eclipse offered to start it using boilerplate. After a little research, it seemed a good thing to try. But on zipping the project up to send to a tester, I found I had a small app with a very large 4mb footprint...

I've found the culprit in myProject/.git/objects/pack
the file is
pack-8bbfc27fb4f49b9b8418123879a14af5e5dd861c.pack and is 3.8mb

Any ideas what this is for? Is it something eclipse has added?

Cheers

Comment: Why do you care about the size of things in the *.git* directory? That won't be deployed as part of your app.

Comment: That is exactly what I was worried about. A search of the boilerplate documentation makes no reference to it at all. It still begs the question though, what is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.git` directory is only used by the [Git](http://git-scm.com/) version control system. We use Git - as many other open source projects do - to manage the source code of the project.

Comment: ahhh & that relates to where boilerplate is uploaded from. Thanks & ta for taking the question rating off -1. I thought that was a bit harsh :-)